Visual Studio Code 1.91.0 not opening on macOS 11
My Device: iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2014) running macOS Big Sur version 11.7.10
Problem: This problem started when I clicked on install update. Only now it doesn't even turn on Visual Studio Code.
Solutions Tried: Deleted Code and ./vscode folder
The Error Log is massive to posted it on this website for all to see
A portion is as follows:
OS Version: macOS 11.7.10 (20G1427)
Report Version: 12
...
System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread: 0 CrBrowserMain Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note: EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY


There was a bug in the 1.91.0 release. See v1.91 does not launch on Catalina or Big Sur due to Fatal error in V8 #219893. It's fixed in 1.91.1. Update to 1.91.1 to get the fix.
(note for SEO juice: a lot of people also get the following in their error message):

Fatal error in V8: v8::Template::Set Invalid value, must be a primitive or a Template

