VS-Code 1.91 does not open on my big sur 11.7. How do i get to use v-scode updates on older Mac OS
I just downloaded the VS Code update 1.91 and it does not work on Big Sur Mac Os 11.7. Is this intended or its just an oversight. How can i use future updates  for vscode on bigsur. Has anyone else experiences this?
After updating i am unable to use the Vscode 1.91 on my macbook pro 2014. When i click the application it just closes immediately

actually, I'm not sure that 1.91 doesn't support Big Sur. There's a highly visible related bug recently. see https://stackoverflow.com/q/78731792/11107541

As per the VS Code requirements documentation:

VS Code is supported on the following platforms:

macOS versions with Apple security update support. This is typically the latest release and the two previous versions.


macOS 11 Big Sur is 3 versions behind the current version as of VS Code 1.91's release, macOS 14 Sonoma. So no, VS Code 1.91 is not supported by macOS 11.
